# Xamarin/MAUI Open Google Maps without going into split screen mode in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, maui, samsung-mobile

I am opening Google maps with the following line of code:

```
 await Map.OpenAsync ( location, options );
```

This was previously working fine. However since upgrading to Android 13, it now opens Google maps in split screen mode, with Google maps at the top and App at the bottom. This only occurs on Samsung phones, it doesn't occur on the Pixel emulator. It occurs in both Xamarin and MAUI (we currently have both versions of the app)

To try and stop this happening, I have tried adding *ResizeableActivity = false* in both the Activity and the Application. This doesn't stop the app from going into split screen, all it does it make the app go fully black when in split screen mode.

I have also tried the following. This works when opening something like AppInfo.ShowSettingsUI(); and stops it opening in split screen, but it doesn't stop Google Maps from opening in split screen.

```
public override void StartActivity(Intent intent)
{
    intent.RemoveFlags(ActivityFlags.LaunchAdjacent);
    base.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

How do I go about stopping this from happening and opening Google Maps in a new full screen window?

Comment: Have you tried other physical machines except Samsung?

Comment: Yes it works fine on all others. Problem just occurs on Samsungs

Comment: You can mark your answer as accepted, that will help others that have the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of VS (17.5)

Comment: Upgraded to VS v17.6 and added the `StartActivity` code as above but maps are still loading in split screen.  Is there something else that needs to be done to fix the problem?

Comment: Are you using MAUI or Xamarin? Have you tried adding the ResizeableActivity = false flag?

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved with the following modification:

- Update the package to the latest stable version in my case 1.7.5
- Add "**ResizeableActivity = false**" in the MainActivity

With these two changes I have solved the split screen problem (Android 13).

Comment: Thanks, updating Xamarin.Essentials to 1.7.5 fixed it for me without setting ResizeableActivity to false.